# process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I failed to build the app and this error appeared , i hope some one can help me i really need to fix this app , please bro ,please sir , please sister , i hope some one with nice brain and clever could help me to fix this error , just this , this error didn't lead me to anything , i am really serous , idont know ho to fix this error bro

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':lib:generateJsonModelDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: Build command failed.
    Error while executing process C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\PROJEK\app cloner pro\DyalWhatsappAccount\lib\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\PROJEK\app cloner pro\DyalWhatsappAccount\lib\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/PROJEK/app cloner pro/DyalWhatsappAccount/lib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\PROJEK\app cloner pro\DyalWhatsappAccount\lib\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

    process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/add-application.mk:49: D:\PROJEK\app: Permission denied
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/add-application.mk:49: cloner: No such file or directory
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/add-application.mk:49: pro\DyalWhatsappAccount\lib\src\main\jni\Application.mk: No such file or directory
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:50: warning: overriding commands for target `D:\PROJEK\app'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:36: warning: ignoring old commands for target `D:\PROJEK\app'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:50: warning: overriding commands for target `cloner'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:36: warning: ignoring old commands for target `cloner'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:130: D:\PROJEK\app: Permission denied
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:130: cloner: No such file or directory
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:130: pro\DyalWhatsappAccount\lib\src\main\jni\Android.mk: No such file or directory
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:563: warning: overriding commands for target `D:/PROJEK'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:33: warning: ignoring old commands for target `D:/PROJEK'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:563: warning: overriding commands for target `.'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:33: warning: ignoring old commands for target `.'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:619: warning: overriding commands for target `cloner'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:50: warning: ignoring old commands for target `cloner'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-all.mk:94: Android NDK: WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!    
    make: *** No rule to make target `pro\DyalWhatsappAccount\lib\src\main\jni\Android.mk'.  Stop.

        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        ... 34 more
    Caused by: Build command failed.
    Error while executing process C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\PROJEK\app cloner pro\DyalWhatsappAccount\lib\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\PROJEK\app cloner pro\DyalWhatsappAccount\lib\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/PROJEK/app cloner pro/DyalWhatsappAccount/lib/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\PROJEK\app cloner pro\DyalWhatsappAccount\lib\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

    process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/add-application.mk:49: D:\PROJEK\app: Permission denied
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/add-application.mk:49: cloner: No such file or directory
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/add-application.mk:49: pro\DyalWhatsappAccount\lib\src\main\jni\Application.mk: No such file or directory
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:50: warning: overriding commands for target `D:\PROJEK\app'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:36: warning: ignoring old commands for target `D:\PROJEK\app'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:50: warning: overriding commands for target `cloner'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:36: warning: ignoring old commands for target `cloner'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:130: D:\PROJEK\app: Permission denied
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:130: cloner: No such file or directory
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:130: pro\DyalWhatsappAccount\lib\src\main\jni\Android.mk: No such file or directory
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:563: warning: overriding commands for target `D:/PROJEK'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:33: warning: ignoring old commands for target `D:/PROJEK'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:563: warning: overriding commands for target `.'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:33: warning: ignoring old commands for target `.'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:619: warning: overriding commands for target `cloner'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/gdb.mk:50: warning: ignoring old commands for target `cloner'
    C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-all.mk:94: Android NDK: WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!    
    make: *** No rule to make target `pro\DyalWhatsappAccount\lib\src\main\jni\Android.mk'.  Stop.

        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.process.ProcessOutputJunction.execute(ProcessOutputJunction.kt:78)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.process.ProcessOutputJunction.executeAndReturnStdoutString(ProcessOutputJunction.kt:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.NdkBuildExternalNativeJsonGenerator.executeProcess(NdkBuildExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:183)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.buildForOneConfiguration(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:354)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.buildAndPropagateException(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:235)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.build(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:156)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildJsonTask.build(ExternalNativeBuildJsonTask.java:35)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        ... 47 more
```

Answer (score 0):

explain your problem in detail so that others will understand. what are you trying to do, and so on.

Comment: icried,,cause cant fix the app